# how to change fontsize of this <string name="app_name"> Helloworld</string>

Tags: android

Iam trying to change the font size in String.xml  Helloworld ..am able to do by  it reflected on titlebar on the Emmulator,problem is my Application contains Locales..have many string.xmls how can i give common font size to all locale string.xmls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.xml should have only the content and while displaying the same u can specify font size.

you can also define a style with font size and that can be used where ever you want to display.

Comment: Thank you Atmaram, Plz let me know how can i change the DialogTitle in List preference...